# Delete one page from CFileCache

Tags: caching, yii, yii-components

I'm using Yii's CFileCache.

In my config file I have:

```
'components'=>array(
  'cache' => array('class' => 'system.caching.CFileCache'),
),
```

If I want to see the effect of data changes on the site I go to the admin portion of the site and flush the cache using `Yii::app()->cache->flush();`.

Is there a way to **delete just a certain page from the cache**?

Secondary question:
If I don't flush the cache, how long will it take the new data to be shown on the website?

Looking in the [code](https://github.com/echothrust/echofish/blob/master/yii/framework/caching/CFileCache.php) the default expire value in the `setValue` method is 1 year, which seems awful long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to your first question, you can delete a certain value

To remove a cached value from cache, call `delete();`
You should be very careful when calling `flush()` because it also removes cached data that are from other applications.

You can set an expiration e.g.

```
Yii::app()->cache->set($id, $value, 30, new CFileCacheDependency('FileName'));
```

this will expire in 30 seconds

[Reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data)

Comment: It turns out the pages weren't being cached by CFileCache but by COutputCache. But since CFileCache was the only cache component in the app's config file, I wasn't aware COutputCache was also being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can set expire date for cache.

```
Yii::app()->cache->set('KEY','VALUE',90); //expires after 90 seconds
```

It is also recommended to use `gc` method. As Yii's official definition:

> gc() removes expired cache files.

For example:

```
Yii::app()->cache->gc();
```

It only removes the expired cache files.